# move_upload_file not work for upload video

Tags: php

I want to upload video (like mp4, wvm, flv) with form submit but move_file_upload() not working.

This is my code :

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $errors = array();
   $allowed_e = array('mp4', 'flv', 'wmv');

   $file_name = $_FILES['video2']['name'];
   $file_e = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   $file_s = $_FILES['video2']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['video2']['tmp_name'];
   $t_name = @$_POST['topic_name'];
    $content = @$_POST['content'];
    $date = date("y-m-d");
   if (in_array($file_e, $allowed_e) == false) {
   $errors[] = 'ext not allowed';
   }

   if ($file_s > 20097152) {
   $errors[] = 'File must be under 20mb';
   }
   

   if (empty($errors)) {
   $rawBaseName = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
      $extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
      $counter1 = 1;
      $counter2 = 1;
       while(file_exists('video/'.$file_name)) {
       $file_name = $rawBaseName . $counter1 . $counter2 .'.' . $extension;
       $counter1++; 
    $counter2++;}
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'video/'.$file_name);
   $video2_up = 'video/'.$file_name;
   if ($posttopic = "INSERT INTO topics (topic_id, topic_name, topic_content, topic_creator, date, video)
        VALUES ('', '".$t_name."', '".$content."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."', '".$date."', '".$video2_up."')" ){
      $conn->exec($posttopic);
     }header("Location: index.php");
       
   

   }else{
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
     echo $error, '</br>';
    }
   }

  }
?>
```

But when I remove that extension allowed and upload some image it works
please give me solution.

Comment: i guess the problem is with the file size. go to php.ini and change upload_max_filesize to 256MB and post_max_size to 256MB, then restart apache and check once

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: @Prasad the error is, file not uploaded to video/

Comment: @Prasad i mean not moving to video/

Comment: @Exprator OMFG THANKS MAN, U SOLVED MY JOB

Comment: haha your are welcome bro @faufau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the file size. Check your php.ini file and increase the limit for following php directives:

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

After making the above changes, restart you web server.

Comment: please accept the answer and upvote if it is useful.